# unable to access function

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I made a program for binary heap given below-

```
       #include<iostream>
     using namespace std;
        /**
         * Construct the binary heap.
         * capacity is the capacity of the binary heap.
         */

class BinaryHeap
        {

           private:
            int   currentSize;  // Number of elements in heap
            int array[];        // The heap array

            void buildHeap( );
            void percolateDown( int hole );
           public:
            bool isEmpty( ) const;
            bool isFull( ) const;
            int findmini( ) const;

            void insert( int x );
            void deleteMin( );
            void deleteMin( int minItem );
            void makeEmpty( );



       public :
       BinaryHeap(  )
        {
         currentSize = 0;
        }
      BinaryHeap( int capacity )
        {
          array[capacity + 1];
         currentSize = 0;
        }
};
int main()
{
     int resp, ch, choice;
     int n, i;
     cout << "enter the size of heap" << endl;
     cin >> n;
    BinaryHeap b(int n);
   cout << "enter the item " << endl;
      cin >> ch;
    b.insert( int ch);


return 0;
}
```

while compiling it gives errors

request for member 'insert' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'BinaryHeap(int)'
and 
expected primary-expression before 'int'

why is this happening and how could it be resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `int` from `BinaryHeap b(int n);` and `b.insert( int ch);` and you are good to go.

When you call a function you shouldn't specify the data type of the variables you call it with.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
b.insert( int ch);
```

to this:

```
b.insert(ch);
```